# Angular CLI - selective usage of script's crossorigin attribute

Tags: html, angular, safari, angular-cli, internet-explorer-11

To sketch out my problem: We have an angular app, which is served by **basic auth** protected server. This app is supposed to run among others in IE11 and Safari 12. And we have **differential** build to cover for es5 and es2015+ environments.

Now when it comes to build-produced *index.html*, Safari 12 **needs** to have `crossorigin` attribute on `<script type="module">` there in order to send BA credentials to the BA-protected server (although the client and server domain match). Without the attribute, it doesn't send them and the request fails with 401. It turns out, that some older browsers, like Safari 12, implement older version of spec for `type=module` script fetching, which doesn't send the auth credentials automatically. Newer browsers implement newer version of the spec and the credentials are sent correctly (that's why Safari 13 works for me).

So my fix for this issue was to set `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute via *angular.json*. This causes every build to produce `<script>`s for both es5 and es2015 bundles with this attribute, which fixed the issue in Safari 12. So far so good.

But then I discovered, that IE11 doesn't handle this attribute well. In fact, the `crossorigin` attr is not supported in IE11, which shouldn't make a difference, but it doesn't send the credentials when sending request for script, regardless of its `type=""`, which naturally fails with 401 again. When I remove the `crossorigin` attribute, it fixes the issue in IE11, but guess what, breaks Safari 12 again.

With all that in mind, the logical solution would be to add `crossorigin` only to es2015 scripts (for Safari 12) and leave es5 scripts intact (for IE11). This is more difficult than it sounds though, because as it seems, angular-cli doesn't have the option to distinguish based on ES target. It just provides an option to set crossorigin on **all** produced scripts.

And this is where the actual questions come in:

1. Is there an easy way to do this with angular-cli? Outside of writing some kind of a node script that does this for me.
2. Am I perhaps approaching this problem from a wrong angle? Is there a better way to solve this credential sending problem?
3. And bonus question: Why isn't IE11 able to handle the (for it) unknown `crossorigin` attribute? I thought unknown attributes are just ignored.

Comment: If you refer to the docs, you can notice that script type='module' is also not supported in IE 11. Ref: https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module Did you tried to identify the browser and load the attribute only for the Safari browser? Does it work? If you did not try then you can have a test.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT That's why we have scripts for both es2015 and es5 bundles in index.html. The former have the type='module' attr, whereas the latter don't.
About the browser identification, I don't want to complicate things too much, browser identification is not the most solid solution. And yes, when I remove the attribute, it works in IE, and when I don't, it works in Safari 12.

Comment: At present, I did not get any other way to achieve this in an Angular project. I also tested on my side and found that crossorigin="anonymous" not giving any error with the IE browser. Currently identifying the browser seems only available way for handling this issue.

Comment: So with crossorigin="anonymous" and BA protected server, you had no trouble fetching the script?

Comment: I solved it for now by having a postbuild npm script that removes the crossorigin attribute from the "es5" `<script>`s.

Comment: It's good to know that you found the solution to the issue. Thanks for updating us with the possible solution to this issue. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of situations.